# WSO2 IS 5.5.0 – Switching between BASIC and IWA authentication dynamically

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 5.5.0. We are able to configure IWA using Federated Authentication (Kerberos). Users are able to login with their windows credentials.
Our application is accessible in INTRANET as well on INTERNET.
We have following requirement.
All the INTRANET users should be authenticated using IWA authentication whereas all INTERNET users should be presented with login page to enter their credentials.
Can you please let us know if this is possible through some configuration?
We tried steps concept in “Advanced Configuration” under “Local and Outbound Authentication Configuration” of Service Provider but not getting expected result.
First Steps in the sequence always gets executed whereas we want some kind of switch between step 1 and step 2.
We want all INTRANET users to follow the /iwa-kerberos authentication and want to display login page for INTERNET users.

We were able to achieve this in WSO IS 5.2.0 by having a switch in our login.jsp to redirect all the INTRANET users to following URL.
/commonauth?idp=LOCAL&authenticator= IWAAuthenticator&sessionDataKey=xxxxxxxxxxxx

In this approach we used to add only “BASIC” authenticator under Step 1 under “Advanced Configuration”